# PHP Zend_Paginator on mySql query using GET

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I am trying to call pages using `Zend_Paginate()` on a query that loads based on a GET search string the query essentially does the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%searchstring%' OR alt_column LIKE '%searchstring%';
```

The query works fine when called via search/submit text form and the URL returns something similar to

```
URLINK.php?search=searchstring
```

However when trying to move onto the next page the program dumps me back to the paginate alternate URL (used for errors or no page display)-- hope this last line makes sense it is late and am doing my best to type this up with transparency.

What is the best method when using paginate against `URL.php?search=searchstring`"?

A bit more on the call to the url

```
//search query 
$search = searchQuery('search', 'list_sql_rows.php');
$results - searchTable($dbRead, $search);
```

search method using the variables above in the order below

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_search'])) { $searchstring = $_POST['searchstring'];
if($searchstring) { header('Location: results.php?search=' . $searchstring); } }
```

This bit works well, but when I try to call the `results.php?page=2` with paginator the system reverts me to the fall back URL `list_sql_rows.php` as mentioned above. Any thoughts/comments are appreciated.

Just to clarify a search field/form from the search.php page sends the `$searchstring` to the results.php page via `$_POST` && `$_GET` as fail safe. The get method sends the `$searchstring` in the URL header so the results of the search DO work on the first page ***results.php?search=$searchstring***. This works just fine. The pagination seems to lose the `$searchstring`, and I wonder if this is due to a loss of the `$_POST`/`$_GET` when paginator begins to 'paginate' it returns URL ***results.php?page=2*** so it seems `$_GET` may not be the method of choice?

**UPDATE**
On the write track now paginate works it is my link structure that is broken. 
**_results_samples.php?search=robert&page=4_** will in fact return page 4 of the paginated results using the word ROBERT

***SOLUTION FOUND VIA  variant suggestion by ROCKYFORD***
variant of recommended method by first persisting `$searchstring`
change to paginate links as shown below

```
<a href='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?search=" . $searchstring . "&page={$page}'>$page</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make sure you preserve the query strings between requests, use Zend_Session_Namespace or Zend_registry.

Everytime Zend_Paginator loads a page when using the DbTableSelect or DbSelect adapters it has to hit the db with the query, it just changes the limit option.

Or you could just dump the whole query result into a Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Array and it will page through the array.

**[edit]**
you are going to have to persist the query string between requests someway so you can put it back in the url string, I usually use Zend_Registry, but then I use the whole MVC stack. You don't seem to be using the whole stack so you'll need another method, probably $_SESSION would work. I'm sure there are many other ways to persist this data.

P.S. you didn't mention which adapter you are using so I'm making some assumptions.

**[edit]**
Personally I always use $_post for this when possible to avoid all this, only seem to have this problem with $_get.

Comment: Search query runs using Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli() and the paginator in use is Zend_Paginator::factory()

Comment: Using a variant of the recommendations the search query is now working, had to _persist_ the $searchstring variable, now the pages are paginating the way they should. Many thanks RockyFord!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the example of correct using of pagination:
in action-method:

```
$select = $clients->getAll();                               
$paginator = new Zend_Paginator(new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($select));
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($this->_getParam('page'));
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage(20);
$this->view->clients = $paginator;
```

in a view script:

```
<?php if (count($this->clients) > 0): ?>
...
    <?php echo $this->paginationControl($this->clients, 'Sliding', 'partials/paginator.phtml'); ?>
<?php else: ?>
        <h3 class="notice">No registered clients found!</h3>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But even if you will fail with this variant, you can always try to compose your own component, Zend only aids us in solving some tasks.

Comment: Search query runs using Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli() and the paginator in use is Zend_Paginator::factory()

Comment: I have a variant of this already in use on a regular ->fetchAll(); this works fine; however, I am now attempting to use with GET via a simple search field/form the first page display subsequent pages do not. Seems I am losing the search string with the GET method if more than one page exists.